# java: Could not find the main class: test/test. Program will exit

Tags: java, class, find, program-entry-point

I was provided some source code sample which i want to test some functions.
Unfortunately, I have problem with executing the program:

```
11:41:31 [linqus@ottsrvafq1 example]$ javac -g  test/test.java
11:41:52 [linqus@ottsrvafq1 example]$ java -classpath . test/test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: test/test (wrong name: test)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: test/test.  Program will exit.
11:42:57 [linqus@ottsrvafq1 example]$
```

What I can do?

Comment: Can you provide your test.java ?

Comment: Please provide the source code of test.java.

Comment: public class test {

  public static final String USER_NAME = "Test";
  public static final String USER_PASSWORD = "TEST";
  public static final String RCA_PRODUCT_NAME = "LPM";

  private static CardManagerAccessPoint cardManagerAccessPoint = null;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
                ExampleInvocation();
        }


  public static void ExampleInvocation() {
....
}

Comment: THere is no package name

Comment: Refer to my solution suggestion. It should work.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have much experience with Java, but as far as I know, you should be using the fully qualified Java class name to run the file :

```
// Assuming that the class is called "test" and is not in any package
java -classpath test test

// If "test" is actually in the package "test" :
java -classpath . test.test
```

Comment: this one seems to be OK and solved my problem partially.
now i have new error:

java -classpath . test.test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gemplus/gxs/api/exception/DeniedAccessException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gemplus.gxs.api.exception.DeniedAccessException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
....

Could not find the main class: test.test.  Program will exit.

Answer (score 1):

To run a class with the java command you need to use . instead of /

Assuming `test` is a class in a package called `test` as your javac command suggests.

E.g.

```
java -classpath . test.test
```

Also you should follow java naming conventions and name your classes starting with an uppercase letter. It should be `test.Test` to make it easier to differentiate between classes and packages

you compilation is correct as / should be used when using javac

Answer (score 1):

You need to run it as:

```
java -classpath test test
```

The first `test` is the name of the directory your `.class` file is in. The second `test` is the name of the Java class you want to run. Usually you need to specify the full package name here, but since your class is in the global package, just passing `test` here will work.

Answer (score 0):

Read the code into an IDE (eclipse, intellij, netbeans) it will probably highlight the problem.

It seems that Your code is missing something simple (i.e. package name).

Answer (score 0):

it might be case problem, your class name is differ that you call from your command.
Suppose your class name is `Test` and you provide `test` in command line.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html